# Display Images in grid view after selecting from gallery

Tags: java, android

I am writing code to select images from the gallery and later to display them on a grid view . I had done the code till allowing the user to select images from the gallery. Now I need help to further move this and display the selected images in a separate gird view . Here I am attaching my code till what I have done.Thanks in advance.

MultiPhotoSelectActivity.java

```
package com.mamakar.gridviewimplementation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author Paresh Mayani (@pareshmayani)
 */
public class MultiPhotoSelectActivity extends BaseActivity {

private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

        //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,  MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy + " DESC");
    //MultiPhotoSelectActivity.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getBaseCont‌​ext()));

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this));
    this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

        System.out.println("=====> Array path => "+imageUrls.get(i));
    }


    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    imageLoader.stop();
    super.onStop();
}

public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
    Toast.makeText(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, "Total photos selected: "+selectedItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + selectedItems.toString());
}

/*private void startImageGalleryActivity(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
    intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
    startActivity(intent);
}*/

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> mList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mContext;
    SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mList = imageList;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
        }

        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }
        });

        mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

        return convertView;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };
}


}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
package com.mamakar.gridviewimplementation;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

/**
 * @author Paresh Mayani (@pareshmayani)
 */
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

}
```

UILApplication.java

```
package com.mamakar.gridviewimplementation;

import android.app.Application;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
public class UILApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them, 
    // or you can create default configuration by
    //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
    // method.
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .threadPoolSize(3)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .memoryCacheSize(1500000) // 1.5 Mb
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
        .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
//  BaseActivity.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getBaseCont‌​ext()));
}
}
```

ac_image_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="btnChoosePhotosClick"
        android:text="Select Photos" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_multiphoto_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get image's path which selected and you can show in custom gridView which include an ImageView. And set the image path.
I think, this repo will help you. It is what how you want.
https://github.com/Cutta/MultipleImagePicker